# Show that a Sylow $q$-subgroup is normal in G, where $|G| = p^2q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G| = p^2q$, where $p, q$ are primes such that $p < q$.

Consider a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$. I want to show that such subgroup is normal in $G$.

Now, by Sylow's Theorems, it will suffice to show that there is only one such subgroup. But the usual divisibility and congruence conditions aren't helping me out here (e.g., I can't seem to derive a contradiction by assuming that the number of Sylow $q$-subgroups is $p$ or $p^2$).

Another approach I've attempted is considering the normalizer of such a group: Call such a subgroup $Q$. It will be sufficient to show that $N_G(Q) = G$. I've got it down to an argument regarding the order of $N_G(Q)$, where I've eliminated all possibilities except for $q$... but, again, I see no reason why $Q$ can't be self-normalizing...

Basically, I've hit this problem with everything I've got and am out of ideas.

Comment: This fails for $p^2q=12$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to prove things that aren't true.  $A_4$ is a counterexample.  It has order $2^2\cdot 3$, and it does not have a normal 3-Sylow.

Order 12 is the only failing case, though.  To get a counterexample,  you need $p^2\equiv1\pmod q$, since $p<q$ precludes $p\equiv 1 \pmod q$. 
But that means $q$ divides $p^2-1=(p-1)(p+1)$, so $q=p+1$ and since both are primes we have p=2, q=3.

You can also check that $A_4$ is the only order 12 counterexample.  Since any counterexample has 4 3-Sylows, it has 8 elements of order 3, so only one 2-Sylow, which is normal.  So it is a semidirect product of a group of order 4 with a group of order 3 with a nontrivial action (since the 3-Sylow is not normal it can't be a direct product).  The cyclic group of order 4 has no order 3 automorphism,  so the 2-Sylow must be the Klein 4 group.  That has only one conjugacy class of order 3 automorphisms, so there is only one such semidirect product, up to isomorphism.

Comment: Oh, that's right. Incidentally, this actually gets me what I need (as this is part of a larger problem I'm working on). So, thanks!